# RecyclerView не заполняется данными

Tags: android, kotlin, recyclerview, arraylist, recyclerview.adapter

В `item` `RecyclerView` есть 2 поля, одно будет заполняться данными из `ArrayList`, другое из базы данных. Сейчас, оба поля временно должны заполняться из `ArrayList`.

Но `RecyclerView` ничего не выводит на экран

Код `ExchangeRateAdapter`:

```
class ExchangeRateAdapter() : RecyclerView.Adapter<ExchangeRateAdapter.ExchangeRateHolder>() {

    private val exchangeRate = ArrayList<ExchangeRateModel>()

    private val list = arrayListOf("AUD", "EUR", "RUB", "JPY")

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ExchangeRateHolder {

        val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val binding: ExchangeRateItemBinding =
            DataBindingUtil.inflate(layoutInflater, R.layout.exchange_rate_item, parent, false)
        return ExchangeRateHolder(binding)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return exchangeRate.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ExchangeRateHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(exchangeRate[position], list[position])

    }

    fun setList(exchangeRateList: List<ExchangeRateModel>) {
       // exchangeRate.clear()
        exchangeRate.addAll(exchangeRateList) // заполнение medications данными
    }

    class ExchangeRateHolder(val binding: ExchangeRateItemBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

        fun bind(exchangeRateModel: ExchangeRateModel, currency : String){
            binding.name.text = currency
               // exchangeRateModel.name
            binding.num.text = currency
                //exchangeRateModel.exchange.toString()
        }

    }

}
```

код `ExchangeRateFragment`:

```
class ExchangeRateFragment : Fragment() {

    private var binding: FragmentExchangeRateBinding? = null
    private var exchangeRateAdapter : ExchangeRateAdapter? = null
    private val exchangeRateViewModel : ExchangeRateViewModel? by viewModel()

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

        binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_exchange_rate, container, false)

        initRecyclerExchangeRate()
        loadExchangeRate()

        return binding?.root
    }

    private fun initRecyclerExchangeRate(){

        binding?.exchangeRateRV?.layoutManager =
            LinearLayoutManager(context)
        exchangeRateAdapter = ExchangeRateAdapter()

        binding?.exchangeRateRV?.adapter = exchangeRateAdapter
    }

    private fun loadExchangeRate(){

        exchangeRateViewModel?.loadExchange?.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            // setList наполняет адаптер данными
            exchangeRateAdapter?.setList(it)
            // notifyDataSetChanged обновляет адаптер
            exchangeRateAdapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
        })

    }
    
}
```

Comment: перенесите весь ваш код из onCreateView в onViewCreated. и никогда, слышите, НИКОГДА не выносите во Фрагментах в шапку Адаптер для Ресайкла.  это утечка памяти. ровно, как и ваш binding. занулите их оба в методе onDestroyView

Comment: Если исключить проблемы с разметкой, то вариант один: список `exchangeRate` у вас пустой и не заполняется, но `getItemCount()` возвращает его размер, тем самым говоря рисайклеру, что адаптер пуст.

Comment: @woesss, Вы оказались правы, спасибо, оформите, пожалуйста, Ваш комментарий в виде ответа, чтобы я мог его принять

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если исключить проблемы с разметкой, то вариант один: список `exchangeRate` у вас пустой и не заполняется, но `getItemCount()` возвращает именно его размер, тем самым говоря рисайклеру, что адаптер пуст.